# Where did the Spider-Suit come from?

Tags: plot-explanation, spider-man-trilogy, spider-man

Watching [Spider-Man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0145487/) last night, after Parker's fateful night with the robber, we flash-forward to him being Spider-Man in full.

However, it is never shown where exactly his costume came from or how it evolved from a *very* rough version of his drawing to the iconic red, black, and blue suit we all know.

How did he obtain and/or maintain this outfit during the movie?

Comment: I was actually thinking about this yesterday.  
The only scene that jumps out in my mind is the one in SP2 where Spiderman tells Hal Sparks that he "made it" as they awkwardly ride down the elevator.  What's funny is that, when it came to the shooting webs, Raimi explicitly stated that he wanted the webs to be organic to spiderman.  His comment was something to the effect of "we are not gonna have some kid with glue make a product that even 3M can't make."

Comment: Which I understand; but then we see this elaborate suit that only a tailor with mad skills could create.  I mean, it's a comic book movie so I just roll with it; but the story behind making that suit would have made an interesting scene IMHO.

Comment: @ray023 good point with the Raimi quote.  He's always been a bit eccentric :p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I can recall (it's been some time since I've seen the movie) there is no explicit explanation of how his suit was made.  The movie just leads the audience to believe or assume that he ended up making it himself.

The process of making a suit isn't very interesting, and the director probably didn't want to waste much time on it, so they probably shot it like this to lead the audience to believe he made it without having to worry about the whole boring process.

Comment: "The process of making a suit isn't very interesting."  I respectfully disagree with this remark.  In Batman Begins, I was very entertained watching Wayne and Alfred design the suit. (_Well... At Least We'll Have Spares_).  The beauty of a superhero movie is the realism they bring to the screen.  You have a real person with a struggle in which you can identify; and you get to evolve with them.  I would enjoy  a scene watching Parker at a linen shop picking out a whole bunch of red and blue; or sitting behind the sewing machine repairing the damage done after a fight.

Comment: @ray023 Makes me wonder how the new Spider-Man will handle the suit, it looks pretty complete.

Comment: I vaguely recall a suit design montage in the movie.  I think I'll have to rewatch it.

Comment: @Keen The montage was design for the wrestling match, but thats when he showed up in sweats, to a bit of comedic surprise.  After that night, there is then a montage of him saving people as Spider-Man

Comment: @TylerShads Ah, you're right.

Comment: @ray023 there were bits and pieces, but they didn't show the actual process that went into making the different pieces.  spiderman's suit is pretty basic, it's fancy spandex.  the entirety of him making it would be "hmm, i like this color, and this color... 'ouch!  pricked my finger while sewing!'"